# Autogenerate clases/files/etc, like using T4 files

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

we have an application running, that most of it are CRUD pages, those pages are created by a couple of T4 files, and is working fine, with some minor touches after the file generation.

the thing is that, we are starting to analyze the possibility to start using net core the thing is that i don't find any t4 files on the EF-Core, so i would like to ask if there is any way of creating those files, i don't know, from the context or something like that.

i can't find anything related to that, although i do see these CSharpDbContextGenerator and CSharpEntityTypeGenerator...

thanks!

Comment: I'm working on a sample of how to do this at https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.TextTemplating

Comment: @bricelam maybe you can help in this project... https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars

Comment: I have! lol, my sample re-uses the APIs Tony and I designed together for his project. I just wanted to show an approach using T4 since it may be more familiar to users coming from EF6.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into pre-made files for this but you could still use T4 templates if you already are used to them. I have successfully used [this](https://github.com/atifaziz/t5) .netcore library to generate classes from T4 templates. The library is called T5. I haven't done particularly complex things with it but I set up a docker container that I use with a simple bash script to generate all files I need.
Not sure this is what you were looking for though.

Comment: the T4 actually works fine, but you don't have the edmx to create the files based on that information, should i read all the cs files on a directory and create the API and the BLL layer based on that?

Comment: Are you saying you have a edmx file and that you cannot read it inside the T4 template or that you want to achive your goal without using it? Sorry but I didn't understand this.